# Is there any option to acquiring printable data than screen shot in android api?

Tags: maps, here-api

Is there any option to acquire printable map data than screen shot, using android api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in premium SDK version.

HERE SDK provides two alternatives to actively fetch map data:

Map data may be downloaded for an arbitrary bounding box or a radius around a route
The first active approach is where you request the download of map data packages which cover an entire country or region using the MapLoader APIs. You do this by selecting from a list of map packages. A map package may be a state (such as California), region, or a country (such as Belgium).

Note: This preloaded map data is stored separately from the map data cache mentioned in the passive download approach above. The amount of space available for map data packages is only limited by the amount of free space on the device.
The second active approach is where you explicitly trigger a fetch of map data through the MapDataPrefetcher APIs by specifying a bounding box or a radius around a route. The resulting downloaded map data is stored in the same cache used in the passive download approach, where the cache size by default is 256 MB

Please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/dev_guide/topics/maps-offline.html

and our example of github : https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/map-downloader